# sum only different id's values with any aggreagte function in postgresql

Tags: group-by, aggregate, postgresql-9.6, window-functions, sum

I need your help. Let's assume that we have a table like below

```
+---------------+-------+--------+----------+
|    barcode    | shop  |   id   | entrance |
+---------------+-------+--------+----------+
| 2014708941747 | shop1 |   3587 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop2 |   3587 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop3 |   3587 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop4 |   3587 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop5 |   3587 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop6 |   3587 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop7 |   3587 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop1 |  44791 |        2 |
| 2014708941747 | shop8 |  65846 |        0 |
| 2014708941747 | shop9 |  83246 |        0 |
| 2014708941747 | shop3 |  92705 |       22 |
| 2014708941747 | shop4 |  98014 |        8 |
| 2014708941747 | shop2 | 103612 |       12 |
| 2014708941747 | shop5 | 109961 |       19 |
| 2014708941747 | shop6 | 115025 |        6 |
| 2014708941747 | shop7 | 126898 |      144 |
+---------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Now I want to know how many quantities exist for the given barcode but `id` must not be repeated. With the above example, our result must be like below

```
+---------------+----------+
|    barcode    | entrance |
+---------------+----------+
| 2014708941747 |      225 |
+---------------+----------+
```

If I do this with a traditional group by `entrance=227` which is not correct. Is there any aggregate function to solve this kind of problem?

We can solve this problem with an inner query and group by combination. But I want to know can we solve this with window functions or not?

Comment: What if there are different values for an ID?

Comment: @stickybit there is no such case

Answer (score 1):

If entrance is always the same per barcode and ID you could first group by barcode and id taking the max entrance and then get the sum grouping by barcode.

```
SELECT x.barcode,
       sum(x.entrance) entrance
       FROM (SELECT t.barcode,
                    t.id,
                    max(t.entrance) entrance
                    FROM elbat t
                    GROUP BY t.barcode,
                             t.id) x
       GROUP BY x.barcode;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But I search that is there any predefined functions in Postgres like window functions.

Answer (score 1):

Give all the values a row_number partitioned by barcode and id. Then filter all the rows that don't have a row_number = 1, and then sum. Viola

```
with x as (
select
*
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by barcode, id order by entrance asc) as row_number
from yourtable
)
select 
barcode,
sum(entrance) as entrance
from x
where row_number = 1
GROUP by barcode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(ENTRANCE) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT BARCODE, ID, ENTRANCE FROM TBL
  )
```

Whether "predefined functions" exist that do this is highly unlikely, given the inevitable requirement to include some kind of DISTINCT-like functionality.